# Session expires very quickly in cakePHP 2.9

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.9

I tried many options in config.php file but no success.
Here the options.
first one:

```
 Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
            'timeout' => 31556926, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
            'cookieTimeout' => 31556926,
            'ini' => array(
               'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 31556926 // 36 hours
             )
));
```

second one:

```
 Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'Session.timeout' => 36000
 ));
```

Please let me know, as session expires in middle of work!

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in your  (app/Config/core.php)

```
 Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'timeout' => 30, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
        'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
        'checkAgent' => false,
        'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
    ));
```

Comment: I would recommend changing 'defaults' => 'cake' to 'defaults' => 'php' since the original question referred to using php for session.  The rest should work though. :)